# c++ ansi escape codes not displaying color to console

Tags: c++, ansi-escape

I am trying to change the color of text in the console.

We are supposed to use a config file to read the ansi escape codes from:

this is what's in my file

```
red     \033[0;31m      #red
blue    \033[0;34m      #blue
green   \033[0;32m      #green
grey    \033[0;37m      #grey
```

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <map>
    using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    string file = "config.txt";
    string line = "";
    string tag = "";
    string ansi = "";
    map <string, string> m;

    if(argc == 2){  
        file = argv[1];
    }
    ifstream in(file, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    if(!in){
        cerr<<"could not open file";
    }

    while (getline(in, line)){
        istringstream iss(line);
        if(iss>>tag>>ansi){
            auto it = m.find(tag);
            if(it == m.end()){
                m.insert(make_pair(tag,ansi));
            }

        }
    }

    for(auto x: m){
        cout<<x.second<<x.first<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\033[0;35mhello";
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure why but only the last print statement actually displays in color the other outputs the ansi escape codes as text.

Here is my output :

```
\033[0;34mblue
\033[0;32mgreen
\033[0;37mgrey
\033[0;31mred
hello (in purple)
```

Comment: I have to apply a fair amount of guessing here but it seems to me that you assume that `\033` in a text file will be interpreted as ESC if you read it into your C++ program. However, this is not the case. The backslash only has a meaning to the parser that is run by the compiler. For text input, it is up to you, the programmer, to treat `\033` as ESC. To the input function, it is just the string `{'\\', '0', '3', '3'}`.

Comment: You will have to parse and convert the escape sequence in your file by yourself, or alter the format of the configuration file.

Comment: I figured it was something like that... so how do I do this?

Comment: Is the format of your config file fixed? The simplest solution would be to simply make the CSI (*control sequence introduction*, the `\033[`) implicit (ie added by your program). This would also make the config file look simpler.

Comment: yeah I think the instructor for this course is pretty strict about formatting. I will just ignore the first four characters of the sequence and manually print the escape sequence before the rest of the sequence. It works! :)

Comment: Reading _\033[0;31m_ from a file is not the same as defining it in a C string as in _"\033[0;31m"_.  To see the difference, read the line, and define the string.  Then dump them in hex.  You'll see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with reading the config.txt files is that the string is read as though it is assigned to be:

```
std::string str = "\\033[0;31m";
```

i.e. the `\` is treated as a character. What you need in code is `"\033"`, i.e. the character represented by the octal number `033`.

You can change the following lines in your code to ignore the `"\\033"` part of the string and print the octal number.

```
    cout << x.second << x.first <<endl;
```

needs to be:

```
    cout << '\033' << x.second.substr(4) << x.first <<endl;
```

With that change, I tried your program on my desktop and it works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing this:

```
cout<<"\033[0;35mhello";
```

C++ offers possibility to write your own stream manipilator like std::endl to handle escape code.

The goal is to write code like this that seems more readable for me:

```
cout << ansi::foreground_magenta << "hello" ;
```

For writing your own stream manipulators you can proceed like this for instance (simple raw implementation, but you will require to take value from your map...):

```
#include <ostream>

namespace ansi {
  template < class CharT, class Traits >
  constexpr
  std::basic_ostream< CharT, Traits > & reset( std::basic_ostream< CharT, Traits > &os )
  {
     return os << "\033[0m";
  }

  template < class CharT, class Traits >
  constexpr
  std::basic_ostream< CharT, Traits > & foreground_black( std::basic_ostream< CharT, Traits > &os )
  {
     return os << "\033[30m";
  }

  template < class CharT, class Traits >
  constexpr
  std::basic_ostream< CharT, Traits > & foreground_red( std::basic_ostream< CharT, Traits > &os )
  {
     return os << "\033[31m";
  }
  ...
 } // ansi
```

Alternatively, C offers possiblity to use #define to create constants.

```
#define foreground_magenta "\033[35m"
```

Answer (score 1):

The escape sequence in the file won't converted to ESC character.

Moreover, your file has common parts.

For that reason, I moved the common parts that contain ESC character to program and had the configuration file have only the color codes.

File:

```
red     31      #red
blue    34      #blue
green   32      #green
grey    37      #grey
```

Program:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    string file = "config.txt";
    string line = "";
    string tag = "";
    string ansi = "";
    map <string, string> m;

    if(argc == 2){  
        file = argv[1];
    }
    ifstream in(file, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    if(!in){
        cerr<<"could not open file";
    }

    while (getline(in, line)){
        istringstream iss(line);
        if(iss>>tag>>ansi){
            auto it = m.find(tag);
            if(it == m.end()){
                m.insert(make_pair(tag,ansi));
            }

        }
    }

    for(auto x: m){
        cout<<"\033[0;"<<x.second<<"m"<<x.first<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\033[0;35mhello";
    return 0;
}
```